# count number of repeating entries

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am fairly new to Databases and I am just beginning to understand the DML/queries, I have two tables, one named customer this contain customer data and one named requested_games, this contains games requested by the customers,  I would like to write a query that will return the customers that have requested more than two games, so far when I run the query, I don't get the desired result, not sure if I'm doing it right.

Can anyone assist with this thanks,

Below is a snippet of the query

```
select customers.customer_name, wants_list.requested_game, wants_list.wantslists_id,count(wants_list.customers_ID)
from customers, wants_list
where customers.customers_ID = wants_list.customers_id
and wants_list.wantslists_id = wants_list.wantslists_id
and wants_list.requested_game > '2';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just include a HAVING clause

```
GROUP BY customers_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

depending on how you have your data setup you may need to do

```
HAVING COUNT(wants_list.requested_game) > 2
```

This is how I like to describe how a query works maybe itll help you visualize how the query executes :)

`SELECT` is making an order at a restaurant....
`FROM` is the menu you want to order from....
`JOIN` is what sections of the menu you want to include 
 
`WHERE` is any customization you want to make to your order (aka no mushrooms)....
 
`GROUP BY` (and anything after) is after the order has been completed and is at your table...

`GROUP BY` tells your server to bring your types of food together in groups
 
`ORDER BY` is saying what dishes you want first (aka i want my entree then dessert then appetizer ).
 
`HAVING` can be used to pick out any mushrooms that were accidentally left on the plate....
 
etc..

Comment: Thanks very much @John Ruddell, your solution worked, i was able to get the information that i needed out of the query.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to write a query that will return the customers that
>   have requested more than two games

For this to happen you need to do the following

> - First you need to use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to group the games based on customers  (`customers_id`)
> - Then you need to use [HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) clause to get customers who requested more than two games
> - Then make this a [SUBQUERY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) if you need more information on the customer like name
> - Finally you use a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) between `customers` and the sub query (`temp`) to display more information on the customer

Like the following query

```
 SELECT customers.customer_id, customers.customer_name, game_count 
 FROM (SELECT customer_id, count(wantslists_id) AS game_count
      FROM  wants_list
      GROUP BY customer_id
      HAVING count(requested_game) > '2') temp
 JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = temp.customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks also, this one seems a bit more complicated but i will give it a try too, will have to do some reading on sub queries